# How to edit data from database in Codeigniter using bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and I don't how to use this.. please help.

here is my view file (manufacturers.php)

```
<thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Name</th>
                <th></th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
            <?php $offset = $this->uri->segment(3, 0) + 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row); ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->manufacturer_name; ?></td>
                    <th>

                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-editmanuf-modal-lg"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>

                        <?php $this->load->view('modals/editmanufacturer');?>

                </tr>

        </tbody>
```

This is my modal for edit (editmanufacturer.php)

```
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="manufacturer_id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID :</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="manufacturer_id" name="manufacturer_id" placeholder="manufacturer_id">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="manufacturer_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="manufacturer_name" placeholder="manufacturer_name" name="manufacturer_name">
</div>
</div>
<br>


<input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

I don't know what to put on my controller and model... please help!!!

Comment: Try Using Ajax On your Anchor tag on click function and make function to open your modal and on that function pass your id in data and get that id  and passed into your modal as a $data['id'],when you load your poup in controller like  echo $this->load->view("modal",$data); and on success bind that html into opening modal div   .. i am sure you will get your value through your id .

Comment: @Amit but how?  can you show some codes on how to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

please include the following tag to your edit.php file i

/"your controller name"/"your contoller function name" id="student_form"  method="post" >

Comment: please include the following tag to your edit.php file in views
   <form role="form"  action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/"your controller name"/"your contoller function name" id="student_form"  method="post" >

Comment: keep this step in your controller in edit function and when your working with views,there is nothing to keep anything in models.......                                                                                                                $this->load->view('your edit.php file name',$result);

Comment: but I'm using modal in bootstrap, so where should I put it?

Comment: just keep  <form role="form" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/"your controller name"/"your contoller function name" id="student_form" method="post" >                                                                                   before <div class="form-group">                                                                in your (editmanufacturer.php)

Comment: it still doesn't make any changes. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try like this .. Hope It Will Helps ..

first your modal main div put in your view file to load the modal like this .

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="add_manufacture_popup"></div>
```

this link is your edit click link

```
      <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="edit_manufacture_popup(<?php echo $row->manufacturer_id;?>);"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

make function to open your edit modal like this .. and pass your manufacture id

```
function edit_manufacture_popup(manufacturer_id)
   {
       //alert(manufacturer_id)


      $.ajax
      ({
          url   : "<?php echo    base_url('manufacture/ajax_edit_manufacture_popup');?>",
          type  : 'POST',
          data  :{manufacturer_id : manufacturer_id},
          success: function(data)
          {
                $('#add_manufacture_popup').html(data);
                $('#add_manufacture_popup').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false 
                });
           }
       });
  }
```

in your manufacture controller make ajax_edit_manufacture_popup function yo load your modal data like this ...

```
function ajax_edit_manufacture_popup()
    {

        //print_r($_POST); die;
        $data['manufacturer_id'] = $_POST['manufacturer_id'];   
        // get your data by manufacture id and passed to the modal 
        echo $this->load->view('modals/editmanufacturer',$data,true);
    }
```

when you load this modal will bind in add_manufacture_popup id of div

finally your modal looks like this ..

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="frm_edit_manufacture" method="post">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>                              
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="manufacturer_id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="manufacturer_id" name="manufacturer_id" placeholder="manufacturer_id" value="<?php echo $manufacture_data['manufacture_id'];?>">
            </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="manufacturer_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :</label>
             <div class="col-sm-3">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="manufacturer_name" placeholder="manufacturer_name" name="manufacturer_name" value="<?php echo $manufacture_data['manufacturer_name'];?>">
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">   
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

after you can update your form with your manufacture id .. i am sure you it will helps you ..